# Check if an object is a type or a subtype

Tags: c#, object, inheritance, types

Consider the following code which checks if an object is of a specific type:

```
public MyMethod(object myObject)
{
    if (myObject.GetType() != typeof(MyClass))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The type is not MyClass");
    }
}
```

How can the type of `myObject` be checked so that it allows *subtypes* of `MyClass`?

Comment: It seems to work, however there is a warning: `The given expression is never of the provided ('MyClass') type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `is` operator.

```cs
if (!(myObject is MyClass))
```

If possible, limit the argument type so the compiler will enforce that rule for you;

```cs
public MyMethod(MyClass myObject)
```

Comment: yeah this makes more sense +1

Comment: this works as desired